# Powershell Script to remove user from Group Memberships

Tags: powershell

I'm practically new.

I'm looking for a powershell script that our agents can run to remove a user from any security group they are a member of except the primary group (domain users)

Where this gets tricky is the script would be run on a machine that is not in the OU the user accounts are on so I need the script to reach out to that OU instead of performing locally.

I tried something like:

```
$User = "jsmith"
$Groups = (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties memberOf).memberOf
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User -MemberOf $Groups -Confirm:$False
```

But that runs on the OU the script is on so it returns it can't find the user object on that OU.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using the `-Identity` parameter, you could use the `-Filter` parameter and the `-SearchBase` parameter. Instead of `-Identity $User` you could use `-Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$User'" -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=company,DC=com'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use the `-Identity` parameter and the `-SearchBase` parameter together as they are mutually exclusive due to being from different parameter sets. Therefore, you have to use the `-Filter` parameter instead of `-Identity`.

Comment: As for your problem, are you really only searching in another OU? And if so, are you sure you have permission to read that OU? Because I can find users in other OUs no problem, even without specifying their OU.

Comment: @DustyVargas You should post that as answer so the OP can accept.

Comment: @DustyVargas hey I finally got it working. How would I go about making it only target security groups and leaving distribution lists alone. I plan to make a separate one specifically to remove distribution lists.